# Postgresql: query date field with empty value

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am writing a small tool in C# to query a database. In the tool I can assign different fields as selection. The SQL query looks like this:

```
            strSQL = $@"SELECT year, titel, date FROM mydb.records 
                        WHERE true
                        AND (year = '{stryear}' or '' = '{stryear}')
                        AND (year = '{strtitel}' or '' = '{strtitel}')
                        AND case when COALESCE('{strdate}', '') <> '' then date = '{strdate}' end
```

This works so far that empty fields are not taken into account in the query. Only with the date field this does not work, here i get an error because of the invalid value.
Is there any other Option to ignore an empty date value in the query?

Greets Markus

nullif not works: and date = nullif('{strdate}', '')

Comment: If you can, it’s probably better to construct your SQL in multiple steps. So you would start with your base SQL statement and the concatenate additional parts to it only if the relevant variable is populated

Comment: You need to define 'empty date' is that `NULL`, which is not a problem `select null::date; null` or is it an empty string `''` which is `select ''::date; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""`?

Comment: @NickW
In the meantime i also think that it is better to build the sql query in several stages. This also increases flexibility.